# How to display the componentProperties options by the selected option in the dropdown?

Tags: plugins, components, octobercms

I'm sure this is very simple but it's proving just a bit beyond me at the moment.

I have made a plugin that I would like to use for displaying galleries which is working fine. However, trying to add the options of the galleries that I have created in my component is proving to be difficult.

When I add the component to a page, I have now got the option to choose all the galleries that I created but displaying the gallery based upon which one I selected is what I have been unsuccessful in doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm sure this is very simple but it's proving just a bit beyond me at the moment.

I have made a plugin that I would like to use for displaying galleries which is working fine. However, trying to add the options of the galleries that I have created in my component is proving to be difficult.

When I add the component to a page, I have now got the option to choose all the galleries that I created but displaying the gallery based upon which one I selected is what I have been unsuccessful in doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Components/Gallery.php:

```
use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
use MartinSmith\Gallerys\Models\Gallery as GalleryModel;

class gallerys extends ComponentBase
{
public $gallery;

public function componentDetails(){
    return [
        'name' => 'Frontend Gallery',
        'description' => 'A gallery for you webpage'
    ];
}

public function defineProperties() {
    $lists = $this->getLists();
    return [
        'galleryName' => [
            'title' => 'Gallery',
            'type' => 'dropdown',
            'placeholder' => 'Select Gallery',
            'options' => $lists
        ]
    ];
}

public function getLists() {
    $agreements = GalleryModel::all()->pluck('name', 'id');
    return $agreements->toArray();
}

public function getList() {
    $agreement = GalleryModel::where('id', $this->property('galleryName'))->get();
    return $agreement->first();
}

}
```

Components/gallery/default.htm:

```
{% set gallerys = __SELF__.gallery %}

{% for gallery in gallerys %}

<div class="container-fluid px-0">

    <div class="gallery">

        <div class="row">

            {% for image in gallery.fullImage %}

            <div class="col-md-4 px-0 home-galleryImg">

                <a href="{{ image.path }}">

                    <div class="gallery-imgOverlay">
                        <p>{{ image.title }}</p>
                        <h5>{{ image.description }}</h5>
                    </div>

                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ image.thumb(650,auto) }}" alt="{{ thumbnail.description }}">

                </a>

            </div>

            {% endfor %}

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

{% endfor %}
```

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7B6x.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this for myself by creating a function that returns the "name" and indexed by the 'id' using the laravel pluck method. `pluck('name', 'id')` The first argument selects the column to use as the value and the second argument selects the column to use as a key. Note* the `toArray()` method I don't think the options field can take collections.

```
public function getLists() {
    $agreements = Agreements::all()->pluck('agrnum', 'id');
    return $agreements->toArray();
}
//returns
array:3 [▼
  2 => "DLE-2"
  4 => "DLE-1"
  5 => "DLE-3"
]
```

Now in my properties area I call the function `$list = $this->getList();`

```
public function defineProperties() {
$lists = $this->getLists();
return [
    'getList' => [
        'title' => 'List',
        'type' => 'dropdown',
        'placeholder' => 'Select List',
        'options'     => $lists
       ]
    ];
}
```

After that you can proceed to do a `Lists::where('id', $this->property('getList'));` or something of that sort in a function to show the selected list or in your case gallery.

My results:
**The CMS Page Backend from component**

```
    public function defineProperties() {
    $lists = $this->getLists();
    return [
        'getList' => [
            'title' => 'List',
            'type' => 'dropdown',
            'placeholder' => 'Select List',
            'options'     => $lists
           ]
        ];
    }

    public function getLists() {
    $agreements = Agreements::all()->pluck('agrnum', 'id');
    return $agreements->toArray();
    }

    public function getList() {
        $agreement = Agreements::where('id', $this->property('getList'))->get();
        return $agreement->first();
    }
```

[image]

**The Webpage from default.htm in the component template folder**

```
{{ d(__SELF__.getList) }}
```

[image]

Also if I do `{{ d(__SELF__.property('getList')) }}` it shows me the value is `"5"`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I have tried what you have suggested but I end up with the following error: Object of class October\Rain\Database\Builder could not be converted to string. Any ideas?

Comment: @MartinJuniorS Could you post the amended code with what I suggested. Where are you getting the error? Viewing the CMS Page in the backend or the webpage itself in the front end? I amended my answer to show you more of what mine looks like. In your Component.php don't be afraid to trace things with dd(); . The die and dump ( dd() ) can be useful to trace where the php execution error occurs.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code and you should see that it is somewhat identical to the code in which you sent over. I left the variables and the function names the same to avoid confusion. As you can see from the screenshot, +attributes does show the correct gallery now and when I change the component to say 'test 2', it does also update but the galleries are not being outputted.

Comment: Oh and also, when I do {{ d(__SELF__.property('galleryName')) }}, I get a value of 18

Comment: If you want to get a specific gallery and specifying it with the component change `{% set gallerys = __SELF__.gallery %}` to `{% set gallerys = __SELF__.getList %}` in your component default.htm.

Comment: Sorry, I realise this is certainly user error. For '{% set gallerys = __SELF__.getList %}', the .getList, is this reference to the function or the property value? It also breaks when I use either .galleryName or .getList as I thought my original .gallery was in reference to the model and not the component. Sorry, I'm making this difficult but the reason for this was to develop a better understanding and being able to expand on websites by building plugins that allowed me to extend functionality of a website. Thanks for all your help so far

Comment: Okay after looking at this again I see what happened. In your `public function getList()` remove the `->first()`. The `where()` method returns a collection because it plans for multiple items to mach the comparison. The `first()` method then takes the first item in that collection. In your default.htm you are using `{% for %}` which expects `{{ __SELF__.getList }}` to be an array. [The documents](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#referencing-self) Says that .getList is a component property.

Comment: Woo! Yes, that did indeed fix the issue.  I'm getting there, just slowly! Thanks for you help

Comment: Hi there, thanks for all your help in the past! Just wondering if you might be able to give me a hand with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020448/how-to-return-the-key-value-from-a-checkbox-list-field-which-automatically-updat - Sorry to be so cheeky!